# How can I update form value from ajax result

Tags: ajax, jsp

I use ajax to retrieve data.
How can I fill that return data to my jsp form.

This is ajax code.

```
$('#ppmerchant').click(function(){
var mNo = $('#inpMerchantNo').val();
$.ajax({ 
    'url' : 'updatePPMerchant', 
    'type' : 'GET', 
    'data' : {
        'merchantNo' : mNo
    },
    'success' : function(data) {
        if (data != null) {
            var info = $(data).find("tab_1_1_2");
            $("tab_1_1_2").html(info.html());
        }
    }
});
```

});

It's show me form design.But not show the value.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Kindly post the relevant html code

Answer (score 0):

If you have a form you can directly set the value using javascript
see the below example

```
<form>
First name:<br>
<input type="text" id="name" name="firstname">
</form>


<script>
 document.getElementsById("name").value = myValue;  
</script>
```

My value is the data you wish to set.

Answer (score 0):

--remove ' '(single quote) in ajax options type--and try rerun !!!

```
$.ajax({ 
url : 'updatePPMerchant', 
type : 'GET', 
data : {
    merchantNo : mNo
},
success : function(data) {
    if (data != null) {
        var info = $(data).find("tab_1_1_2");
        $("tab_1_1_2").html(info.html());
    }
}
});
```